# How to get current document library by URL in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

Beside query string root folder

how do i get the current doc library list(ListName) from below example url

http://site/subsite/ListName/Forms/AllItems.aspx

any standard way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
string listname = "Not a list";
try
{
    SPList list = web.GetList(HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);
    if (null != list)
    {
        listname = list.Title;
    }
}
catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException) { }
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(listname);
```

Comment: If the current URL is valid for a list, SPContext.Current.List would probably also work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://site/subsite/ListName/Forms/AllItems.aspx"))
using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb()) {
  SPList list = web.GetListFromUrl("http://site/subsite/ListName/Forms/AllItems.aspx");
}
```

Comment: if i need this dynamically, for eg, the url is a home page of the site, will it throw exception if the page doesnt contain the list, or the page url doesnt equal to a list url

Comment: I didn't understand your question, but you can also use relative urls. Also, you may want to try if SPWeb.GetList will work for you instad of GetListFromUrl.
And, if list does not exist, it will surely throw you an exception (Probably SPException)